# What could be causing multi-dimensional numerical integration inconsistency?

Tags: numerical-analysis, c++, integration, mathematica

I'm trying to numerically integrate a multi-dimensional expression. The integrand is complicated; for example this is the integrand for $N=4$:
$$\begin{aligned}&x_1^6x_2^5x_3^3x_4^2(x_1-x_1x_2)(x_1-x_1x_2x_3)(x_1-x_1x_2x_3x_4)\times{}\\&{}\times(x_1x_2-x_1x_2x_3)(x_1x_2-x_1x_2x_3x_4)(x_1x_2x_3-x_1x_2x_3x_4)\end{aligned}$$

And I'm most interested in expressions that have even larger $N$. The integration limits in my trial case are $x_1$ from 0 to 10, and everything else from 0 to 1.

To numerically integrate this I'm using Mathematica while double checking with the VEGAS integrator in C++ ([via the GNU scientific library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Monte-Carlo-Examples.html#Monte-Carlo-Examples)). The problem is the two integrators match for lower dimensions but not for higher ones. The agreement is great for $N =2, 3$, but for $N=4, 5$ there's a considerable discrepancy of about a factor of 5 that gets worse with higher $N$. Agreement doesn't fail completely; the results are still of the same order of magnitude, but a factor of 5 is too large for comfort especially with both integrators reporting error bars much lower than this.

I am unfamiliar with the internals of both integrators and how numerical integration in higher dimensions works. **Is there a (non-bug) reason for why the two integrators give the same results at low dimensions but not at higher dimensions?** If the only possible explanation is "a bug in your code" that's fine, but if there's some other possibility I'd like to check that out too.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you have very high powers of $x$, so over $[0,1]$ (assuming that's the interval) it's a very lopsided integrand, making it more difficult for Monte Carlo methods. So try a substitution that gets rid of pure powers of variables, i.e. $x_1=u_1^{1/13}$, etc., then maybe factor out the very small constant factor you'll get because that can mess with default tolerances, ([like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dbbb41437318804df90586f5bb63cf4f)), and check if that does anything.

Comment: What does your boundary look like?

Comment: @user14717 $x_1$ from 0 to infinity, the rest are from 0 to 1.

Comment: @user14717 sorry, it should be $x_1$ from 0 to 10. The integral to infinity is because I've already excluded an exponential term that should be in the integrand as well.

Comment: @Kirill that's a good point. Thanks. I tried your suggestion and it threw up even more confusing results (the Mathematica results are somehow conditional on the power I choose for $u$ ...) but I guess that's still some progress - at least I know where to look further.

Comment: Can't you integrate some part analytically and then numerically?

Comment: @Allure: Could you post your code?

Comment: Can't you just do this integral in closed form? It's just a long sum of products of powers.

Comment: @Allure The results could well be conditional on the variable transformation if it determines how well-behaved the integrand becomes. Also the variable $x_1$ seems to factor out completely.

Comment: I'm with @kirill: Your integrand is a polynomial, and your integration bounds are boxes. It's easy to integrate this by hand, on a piece of paper, one variable at a time.

Comment: Yes it's analytically solvable, but this is a simplified integrand of the one I'm really interested in (which includes a very complex exponential term). This simplified integrand still shows behaviour I don't understand re the two integrators however. I need some time to get some sense of where the divergence is happening.

Comment: I found the answer to my problem. Unfortunately it's also the least interesting answer: a bug in my code. Correcting the bug fixes the issue for N=4 and drastically reduces the discrepancy for N=5. Thanks for the ideas (which helped locate the bug), but now the question is badly posed. There's a new question though, which is about why different integration methods give different answers in Mathematica. Should I edit the OP or just ask a new question?